# using ajax to update posts in rails view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

How do I write the javascript for adding the post to on clicking the "Submit Post" button with Ajax?Also, will the javascript file be called index.js.haml or create.js.haml?
Here are the relevant files:

index.html.haml:

```
.post#new_post    
    - @posts.each do |post|
        = post.body
    = render partial: "form"
```

_form.html.haml:

```
= bootstrap_form_for @post, remote: true do |f|
    = f.text_area :body, label: "", required: true
    = f.submit "Submit Post", class: "button"
```

Posts Controller (index and create methods):

```
def index
    load_posts # a method I use for loading posts
end

def create
if @post.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html do
      flash[:success] = "Saved."
    end
  end
else
  load_posts
  flash.now[:error] = "Sth went wrong. "
  render :index
end
```

end

JS for ajaxifying:

```
$('#new_post').append('#{escape_javascript(render(@post))}');
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a file create.js.haml in your views/posts and add following

```
$('#new_post').append("<%= @post.body %>");
```